# Is there any pre-defined file to define the variables for jmeter?

Tags: variables, properties, jmeter

I already have a jmeter configuration in my project. I can see a few variables already defined like "${__P(threads)}" for the number of users in ThreadGroup. There are many other variables like these. I am checking where these are defined? I checked in jmeter.properties, user.properties and system.properties.

I tried checking http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html for the location of definition. But, I couldn't find any help.

Is there any pre-defined file to define the variables for jmeter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People frequently use ${__P(threads)} for passing command-line parameters to test plan. You may start jmeter with command line like

```
bin/jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -l results.jtl -Jthreads=100
```

This allows you running jmeter with different number of threads without modifying test plan in GUI.